# PHP MySQL Group By result in array

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

```
**********************
* id  *  typ  *  cl  *
**********************
* 1   *  1    *  1   *
* 2   *  4    *  1   *
* 3   *  7    *  1   *
* 4   *  2    *  2   *
* 5   *  4    *  2   *
* 6   *  8    *  2   *
**********************
```

hi frnz, 
I have a problem with mysql group by... tired of looking on the google so finally posting it here...
my table structure is as showing above.
I am using the following query...

```
$sql2w=executeQuery("select * from logo group by cl  ");
    while($line2=mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){ 
    echo $line2['typ'];
}
```

I am getting 1 and 2 in the result, but I want the result in this format..
1,4,7 and 2,4,8 in string or in array format...

I hope I am clear what I want...

I am only getting the first row values of "typ" column but I want all rows values in array after grouping the "cl" column..

Thanks in advance

Comment: @eggyal: I'm guessing "friends"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```sql
SELECT cl, GROUP_CONCAT(typ) FROM logo GROUP BY cl
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39466/1/0).

Comment: @user2437172: Unless you alias it otherwise, the resultset column will be named `GROUP_CONCAT(typ)`, so you would need to access it accordingly - `echo $line2['GROUP_CONCAT(typ)'];`.

Comment: as a variant you can use some alias for group concat for example GROUP_CONCAT(typ) as typs